# Vetor de strings em C

Tags: c, string

Sei que para definir uma palavra (string) em C, é necessário utilizar um vetor de caracteres, com número definido de caracteres que serão utilizados. Porém, de que forma posso utilizar um vetor de várias palavras, ou seja, um vetor de strings? O motivo da minha pergunta é um exercício no qual devo criar um vetor que armazene o nome de 10 produtos. Desde já obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há varias formas de fazer isso. Vou falar as que eu acho mais simples.

Se você não que mudar as strings, pode simplesmente fazer:

```
const char *a[2];
a[0] = "blah";
a[1] = "hmm";
```

Quando você faz assim, será alocado um array de dois ponteiros para `const char`. Esses ponteiros apontam para as strings estáticas `“blah”` e `“hmm”`.

Se você quiser ser capaz de mudar o conteúdo das strings, faça algo assim:

```
char a[2][14];
strcpy(a[0], "blah");
strcpy(a[1], "hmm");
```

Desta forma serão alocados dois arrays consecutivos de 14 chars cada. Depois é só copiar o conteúdo das strings estáticas neles.

Traduzido do original em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1088667

Comment: Outra possibilidade é utilizar alocação dinâmica de memória declarando um ponteiro para char e utilizando a função malloc com o tamanho desejado.